# What's the probability that a random vector lies in nullspace of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Suppose that $\mathbf{x}$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$, and that $\mathbf{A}$ is an $m\times n$ fat matrix (i.e., $n>m$) with $\text{rank}(\mathbf{A})=m$. Clearly the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$ is non-trivial. What is, the probability that $\mathbf{x}$ is in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$, i.e., $P(\mathbf{x} \in \text{Null}\left(\mathbf A) \right)$?

I have no background to answer questions of those kind --questions that aim to answer the probability of a vector belonging to a subspace-- but I recall Stephen Boyd talking in an online EE263 lecture about the probability of a vector belonging to the range of a matrix, so I guess those questions are answerable. My intuition is that the probability that I'm seeking, $P(\mathbf{x} \in \text{Null}\left(\mathbf A) \right)$, is zero because I have the feeling that this question can be related to computing the probability of a single point in a continuous distribution, which is zero.

More specifically, this would be my attempt to answer. To simplify matters, let me assume that $\mathbf{x}$ is a Gaussian random vector with mean $\boldsymbol{\mu}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Then, we aim to answer the probability of $\mathbf{Ax=0}$. We can define a new random vector $\mathbf{y:=Ax}$. This new random vector, $\mathbf{y}$, is Gaussian as it is a linear transformation of $\mathbf x$. Then, $$P\left(\mathbf{x} \in \text{Null}(\mathbf A)\right)=P\left(\mathbf{Ax=0}\right)=P\left(\mathbf{y=0}\right).$$

As long as $\text{rank}(\mathbf A) = m$ is greater than zero, $P\left(\mathbf{y=0}\right)$ must be 0 because the probability $P\left(\mathbf{y=y}_0\right)$ is 0 for any point $\mathbf{y}_0$.

Is this reasoning correct? Moreover, can I generalize it to *any* continuous distribution or at least any thin-tailed distribution? If so, how can I show this? As a last question, can the same reasoning be used to show that the probability of a random vector belonging to the range of a strictly skinny matrix is zero?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your intuition is right. If the null space isn't  everything then it's a proper subspace. which is very thin - measure $0$ with any reasonable assumption on the distribution.

Comment: The null space is a subset of $\mathbb R^n.$ Your random vector is in $\mathbb R^{K}.$ Do you want $K=n,$ or is $K$ a random variable, too? In any event, there is no uniform probability on $\mathbb R^K,$ so it requires you to specify what you mean by a "random vector." You can pick a random direction by picking a point (uniformly) on the sphere, for example.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant strictly $K=n$ (corrected now -- replaced $K$ with $n$). By random vector I mean an $n$-dimensional vector whose entries are continuous but unknown (hence I believe random is appropriate). While I have no reason to pick a particular distribution, I can realistically assume that it's a thin-tailed distribution.